# SQL文だけでバイナリ（blob）をINSERTしたい

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-server

ファイルを使わず、純粋にSQL文だけでバイナリデータ（blob）をINSERTしたいです。
Oracleでは[この記事](http://www.shift-the-oracle.com/plsql/lob/blob-read-write.html)にあるように16進数表現で実現できるようです。

```
INSERT INTO BLOB_MEDIA (CONTENT_ID, MEDIA)
   VALUES ( 1, HEXTORAW('3E00210102CDA000C9') )
```

PostgreSQLとSQLServerではどのようにすれば良いでしょうか？

Comment: PostgreSQLとSQLServerで質問を分けようとしましたが、質問が重複していると投稿が弾かれてしまいました

Answer (score 11, accepted):

SQL Serverでは`binary`値を`0xABCDEF0123456789`のように引用符なしの`0x`付き16進数で記述することが出来ます。

Answer (score 3):

PostgreSQLは自己解決できました。
`decode`を使うと、16進数文字列をバイナリデータに変換できるようです。

```
insert into BLOB_TABLE ID, BIN_DATA) values ('id1', decode('ABCDEF0123456789', 'hex'));
```